# SQL auto increment pgadmin 4

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a simple database with an number generator but why do I get the error below?

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
>   LINE 2: IDNumber int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Finance
(
    IDNumber int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FinName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(IDNumber)
);
```

Comment: Which SQL implementation are you using? (Oracle / Microsoft / MySQL/ Postgres)

Comment: I am using pgadmin 4

Comment: @bozzy . . . pgadmin is an interface, it is not a database.

Comment: so postgres then?

Comment: You should (serial) data type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For Postgres you have to use `SERIAL`

```
CREATE TABLE Finance
(
    IDNumber SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    FinName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Since Postgres 10 you can use (and it is preferred way) identity (int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY). Sadly this is not yet supported neither by pgadmin3 nor pgadmin4.

Answer (score 81):

The subject of the question mentions pgAdmin 4, so here's how to do it there.

First, add a column to your table, then click the little edit icon:

[image]

Then go to Constraints and select the Identity type:

[image]

This generates SQL similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table_name
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Filling out the information is equally required.

Comment: showing the create script, shows default: ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 )

Answer (score 18):

IN pgadmin-2.
step 01:
create seq: [image]

and set info:

[image]

step 02: go to ID in table and set constraints

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a MySQL syntax which won't work in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE Finance
(
    IDNumber int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FinName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

The following code should work for SQL Server.

`IDENTITY(1,1)` is SQL Server's way of saying "auto increment".

The starting value for `IDENTITY` is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

So : `IDENTITY(startvalue, incrementvalue)`

Comment: `SQL` is a language for querying databases. "This should work for SQL" therefore is a statement that doesn't make sense. What you propably wanted to say was "MS-SQL", which is not the same as "SQL".

Comment: @waka thats right, I am used to saying sql after spending alot of time talking about it. My bad

Answer (score 1):

if it is sql the syntax is the following

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int
);
```

Comment: Is this from w3s? I am pretty sure they always use id, lastname, firstname and age. Especially since you can't even take the time to change the col names

Comment: `SQL` is a language for querying databases. "If it is SQL" therefore is a statement that doesn't make sense. What you propably wanted to say was "MS-SQL", which is not the same as "SQL".

Comment: How does this even get upvoted? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 0):

there are two options; one is to use the "datatype" serial or create a sequence and use this sequence as a default value for your integer as follows:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE your_seq;
     CREATE TABLE foo(
       id int default nextval('your_seq'::regclass),
        other_column TEXT);

     INSERT INTO foo(other_column) VALUES ('bar') RETURNING *;
```

It is important to note that specifying a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL);
```

is equivalent to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
  CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq'));

  ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

More information about serial can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).