# pgAdmin primary key in a table does not automatically get an auto increment

Tags: sql, insert, auto-increment, pgadmin

how do I auto increment in pgAdmin in my table? I should be able to INSERT and create a new row but the error is telling me that my primary key is null. How do I make my primary key automatically increment?

**The Table:**

[image: 1]

I tried this INSERT but it does not follow through because my primary key is not auto incrementing:

[image: 2]

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446399/sql-auto-increment-pgadmin-4

Comment: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/column_dialog.html this should solve your problem ;)

Answer (score -3):

```
CREATE TABALE PUBLIC (id INT,
              group_id INT,
              parent_id INT,
              jid VARCHAR);
```

Run this first, then

```
SELECT*
FROM PUBLIC
```

Then try and input your figures. It should work this way.

Comment: This isn't an answer! 1st you have a typo here (CREATE TABLE...), 2nd this isn't the table name, it is the schema name you provided, 3rd if you do this by script, write it correctly, set id as PK, add Identity(1,1) etc.

Comment: public is the table name, you can see he was trying to import into public and what's the typo error yo are taking about please

Comment: no the table name is public.hms_bbr_group_user -> [schema].[table] ;) - your typo: `CREATE TABALE`-> `CREATE TABLE`- and what you do here is creating a table without PK ...